# Simulating iterations multiple times?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm super new to using Excel, so I don't really know where to start with this problem. I have a bit of a simulation as shown below, but I want to "use" it about 100 times, with different demand variables (15,20,25,30, and 35). I tried using this tutorial, http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introduction-to-monte-carlo-simulation-HA001111893.aspx, but I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone help me out?

```
produced        15                  
rand#           0.906996057                 
demand          35              0.1     15
unit prod cost  1               0.2     20
unit price      1.95            0.3     25
unit disp price 0.5             0.25    30
                                0.15    35
revenue 7.5                 
total var cost  15                  
total disposing revenue 0                   
profit  -7.5
```

Comment: If you want to model something multiple times in Excel you have two clear options: 1. Structure your data differently and use rows to represent each individual trial. 2. Use VBA to run your test multiple times and return the analysis you are looking for. My suggestion here is to use option 1

Answer (score 1):

Use [Data Tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/calculate-multiple-results-by-using-a-data-table-HP010072656.aspx) in Excel. They are specifically for "running" the same formula/worksheet for different values.

Based on your data (as far as I understand what you're doing), I'd say you should follow these steps:

- Put the values you want to evaluate under each other, each in a separate row (see column D in the example).
- Change your "demand" cell to a formula, referencing to the *first* value for demand out of the list you just created (in the example, I put `=D2` in B1)
- Create column labels next to it with the outcomes you want to see (revenue, total var cost, ...) (cell E1 in the example)
- In the *first row only*, reference to the cell that contains the outcome (in the example, I put `=B2` in E2)
- Select the range where the data table should be (D2:E6 in the example)
- Select "Data table" (Excel Ribbon "Data", "What-if analyses", "Data table...")
- Let Excel know what cell to change (put `=B1` in `Column input cell` and leave `Row input cell` empty) and press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Example sheet (blue arrows show cell references):
[image: Excel Data table example]